# React @redux/toolkit not re-rendering component when state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wiles-funk0?file=/src/App.js

**Problem**: When I update the state of my store the components are not re-rendered. In the above example you can see from the console that the data is correctly fetched, but the component is not re-rendered and keep rendering just `Loading...`.

**Expected behavior**: When I update the state, the components are re-rendered.

I found a workaround by using useState in the component and subscribing to store changes like:

```
store.subscribe(() => setComponentState(store.getData())
```

This basically forces a re-render each time the data is updated.

**I can mutate state**: In the official docs they say that you can mutate the state since it has some magic that allows to do so (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-reducers-with-createreducer), hence that's not the issue.

Anyone has any idea about what's the appropriate way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [useStore docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usestore), it states that the hook shouldn't be used in an app because it doesn't cause the component to re-render:

> // EXAMPLE ONLY! Do not do this in a real app.

> // The component will not automatically update if the store state changes

Instead, you should be using [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) instead.

On that note, how you have your codesandbox example would cause an infinite re-render since `dispatch(fetchData());` is called every time the redux state is updated. Instead, you'll want to place it within `React.useEffect`.

For example, using `useSelector` with `useEffect`:

[image: Edit Redux - useSelector]

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer on Github: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/942#issuecomment-807813092

> You should not be using the useStore hook. You should be using the
> useSelector hook, which subscribes to store updates:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#reading-state-from-the-store-with-useselector
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#reading-data-with-useselector
- https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector